# Pull replication(or sync) fails with remote sync gateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am currently working on a PoC to understand the CouchBase lite sync functionality(with Java application). The pull and push replication worked absolutely fine when the sync-gateway was running **locally** on my machine.

Now when I move my sync-gateway to a **Remote machine**, the pull replicator doesn't work. But the push works fine. From the following logs on the client seems like there has been some error with pull replicator.

```
JavaSQLiteStorageEngine
PULL replication event. Source: com.couchbase.lite.replicator.Replication@29fc9a67 Transition: INITIAL -> RUNNING Total changes: 0 Completed changes: 0
Mar 25, 2016 6:04:53 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
SEVERE: ChangeTracker: com.couchbase.lite.replicator.ChangeTracker@2ca40c2c: Change tracker got error 404
Mar 25, 2016 6:04:53 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
SEVERE: Sync: Change tracker stopped during continuous replication
PULL replication event. Source: com.couchbase.lite.replicator.Replication@29fc9a67 Transition: RUNNING -> IDLE Total changes: 0 Completed changes: 0
Mar 25, 2016 6:05:04 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
SEVERE: ChangeTracker: com.couchbase.lite.replicator.ChangeTracker@1b3ae860: Change tracker got error 404
Mar 25, 2016 6:05:04 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
SEVERE: Sync: Change tracker stopped during continuous replication
```

Following is my sync-gateway logs

```
2016-03-25T18:19:03.210Z HTTP:  #267: GET /test/_local/fc25dac22b1cec1454f09c3ea41f763bc4a46b20  (as mehtab.syed)
2016-03-25T18:19:03.210Z HTTP: #267:     --> 404 missing  (0.2 ms)
2016-03-25T18:19:03.214Z HTTP:  #268: GET /test/_local/31d8e5f89b0db31be77ea73f950068c2d5fe11f8  (as mehtab.syed)
2016-03-25T18:19:03.214Z HTTP: #268:     --> 404 missing  (0.2 ms)
2016-03-25T18:19:03.340Z HTTP:  #269: GET /test/_changes%3ffeed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs&active_only=true?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs&active_only=true
2016-03-25T18:19:03.340Z HTTP: #269:     --> 404 unknown URL  (0.2 ms)
2016-03-25T18:19:13.475Z HTTP:  #270: GET /test/_changes%3ffeed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs&active_only=true?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs&active_only=true
2016-03-25T18:19:13.475Z HTTP: #270:     --> 404 unknown URL  (0.2 ms)
2016-03-25T18:19:23.601Z HTTP:  #271: GET /test/_changes%3ffeed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs&active_only=true?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs&active_only=true
2016-03-25T18:19:23.601Z HTTP: #271:     --> 404 unknown URL  (0.2 ms)
```

Further, I am using cookie authentication and following is my sync-gateway configuration.

```
{
  "interface": "127.0.0.1:4988",
  "adminInterface": "127.0.0.1:4989",
  "log": [
    "CRUD",
    "REST+",
    "Access"
  ],
  "databases": {
    "test": {
      "server": "walrus:",
      "users": {"GUEST": {"disabled": true,"admin_channels": ["*"]}
      },
      "sync": `function sync(doc,oldDoc){
        if(doc.type=="user"){
          channel("u-"+doc._id)
          access(doc.owner,"u-"+doc._id)
        }else if(doc.type=="expense"){
          channel("e-"+doc.owner)
          access(doc.owner,"e-"+doc.owner)
          access(doc.approver,"e-"+doc.owner)
        }else{
          channel(doc.channels)
        }
      }`
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Hmmm it looks like the URL query marker `?` is getting encoded mistakenly...(just as a note to whoever comes in to give an actual answer)

Comment: Yeah, the changes feed URL makes no sense — besides the over-encoded "?" it's got several repeated parameters. Not being familiar with the Java code I have no idea how this could happen.

Comment: After lot of digging I figured out the problem isn't with the couchbase sync . The repeated parameters where added due to some faulty configuration of Nginx server.